# what is the process to do automation

Tags: html, cloud

Where it is used and how can you excute and why do you want to use them . YOu please understand the reason on your own and explain

To excute at org level and it should be well used in the orverall company and it should be error flow and proism for ce suteand information should reflect
u should maintain

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.